# How to control the timing of CSS3 animation

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations, line-drawing

I'm working on the SVG line drawing animation as shown below.

[image]

So what am I doing is animate the ear by using `stroke-dasharray` and continue with the dots.

I managed to finish the ear drawing, but I don't know how to control the dots' timing. Following are my animation steps:

1. Ear drawing animation within 5s
2. After 5s, continue with the dots animation (animate row by row)
3. When finish the dots animation, loop back to the 1st step

This is my code, but it blinking gradually. How do I adjust the timing?

```css
.firstpath {
  stroke-dasharray: 1500;
  animation: firstanimate 5s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes firstanimate {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.secondpath {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  animation: secondanimate 5s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes secondanimate {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.thirdpath {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  animation: thirdanimate 5s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes thirdanimate {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.row1col1 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation: blink 2s step-start 0s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink 2s step-start 0s infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="841.89px" height="595.28px" viewBox="0 0 841.89 595.28" enable-background="new 0 0 841.89 595.28" xml:space="preserve">

  <g>
    <path class="firstpath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
   M253.441,284.167c0,0-0.883-14.535,15.429-18.551c5.364-1.32,15.943-0.665,21.667,6.79c13.859,18.051-3.235,32.286-8.087,37.262
   c-4.853,4.979-7.713,21.027-17.543,20.528c-9.829-0.497-12.69-6.717-12.317-11.818" />

    <path class="secondpath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
   M285.249,285.252c0,0,0.654-8.212-8.864-10.544c-9.519-2.334-16.796,8.211-10.825,17.449c2.613-1.12,5.226,0.652,5.599,2.52
   c0.373,1.866-1.213,4.199-3.826,4.199" />

    <path class="thirdpath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
   M257.815,307.553c0,0-3.732,5.879,2.333,8.118c6.065,2.241,5.318-8.118,8.865-9.237c3.545-1.119,11.943-2.519,11.943-10.265
   c0-7.744-6.398-16.451-17.522-11.958" />
  </g>

  <line class="row1col1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="319.41" y1="287.987" x2="324.156" y2="286.627" />

  <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="328.667" y1="285.335" x2="332.744" y2="284.167" />

  <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="338.25" y1="301.171" x2="343.41" y2="301.171" />

  <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="328.667" y1="301.171" x2="333.75" y2="301.171" />

  <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="319.41" y1="301.171" x2="324.156" y2="301.171" />

  <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="313.741" y1="314.625" x2="319.41" y2="315.987" />

  <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="323.741" y1="316.746" x2="329.667" y2="318.142" />

</svg>
```

Comment: I hope the updated snippet in my answer solved your problem completely. If it did, please consider accepting the answer (click on the hollow tick mark below the voting buttons next to the answer). That is generally the way we mark a problem as *solved* here.

Comment: Yes, you did. But I need to adjust the timing to make it more faster. Thank you so much for your answer. Voted yesterday.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstand, I thought you said about the voting. I have clicked it because your answer solved my problem. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. No worries :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the parts of the shape are formed, this would require multiple keyframe animations to work the way you intend for it to.

The following are what you have to do:

- The ear animation though it is expected to complete at `5s` mark should not start its next iteration till the animation of the lines are completed. That is, the ear should stay idle during the amount of time taken by the lines to complete their animation. Hence, we have to set `animation-duration` for the ear such that it covers the amount of time required for the lines to complete their animation. Here, each line component takes `1s` and so total `animation-duration` for all elements (ear and lines) would be `12s`.
- The ear animation should be complete at `5s` mark (out of a total duration of `12s`) and hence the `from` - `to` keyframe setting should be replaced with percentages. Ear animation should start at `0%` and attain its completion at `41%` (which is roughly the `5s` mark). From there, it should hold its position till `100%` (`12s`) mark (that is basically till the lines complete their animation).
- Each line component should start after their previous part has completed its animation and so the `row1col1` should start at `41%` which is when the ear becomes fully visible (till that point it should remain invisible).
- The `row1col1` needs `1s` to animation (which is roughly `8%` of `12s`) and hence the `row1col2` should wait till `49%` of the total duration to start its animation. Similarly `row2col1` should start at `57%`, `row2col2` should start at `66%` and so on.
- If the lines need to slowly fade in, then make it start with `opacity: 0` at `41%` and get `opacity: 1` at `49%` (for `row1col1` and so on for the rest). On the other hand if you need them to appear instantaneously, reduce the percentage where it gets `opacity: 1`. In the snippet, I have made the `row1col1` reach `opacity: 1` at `42%` itself (which is like `0.12s`).

**Notes:**

- I have also modified the `stroke-dasharray` settings of the ear's components to avoid the delay that was originally there between completion of ear's animation and start of the line's animation.
- I would also recommend you to get some SVG expert's help to check if the no. of parts can be minimized as it would reduce no. of keyframes required etc. Unfortunately, my SVG knowledge is limited and so I can't help much with it.

```css
.firstpath {
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  animation: firstanimate 12s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes firstanimate {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  }
  41% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.secondpath {
  stroke-dasharray: 100;
  animation: secondanimate 12s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes secondanimate {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
  41% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.thirdpath {
  stroke-dasharray: 65;
  animation: thirdanimate 12s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes thirdanimate {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 65;
  }
  41% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
line {
  opacity: 0;
}
.row1col1 {
  animation: blink 12s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
  41% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  42%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }  

}
.row1col2 {
  animation: blink2 12s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes blink2 {
  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.row2col1 {
  animation: blink3 12s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes blink3 {
  57% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  58%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.row2col2 {
  animation: blink4 12s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes blink4 {
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  67%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.row2col3 {
  animation: blink5 12s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes blink5 {
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  76%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.row3col1 {
  animation: blink6 12s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes blink6 {
  84% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  85%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.row3col2 {
  animation: blink7 12s linear forwards infinite;
}
@keyframes blink7 {
  92% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  93%, 100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="841.89px" height="595.28px" viewBox="0 0 841.89 595.28" enable-background="new 0 0 841.89 595.28" xml:space="preserve">

  <g>
    <path class="firstpath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
   M253.441,284.167c0,0-0.883-14.535,15.429-18.551c5.364-1.32,15.943-0.665,21.667,6.79c13.859,18.051-3.235,32.286-8.087,37.262
   c-4.853,4.979-7.713,21.027-17.543,20.528c-9.829-0.497-12.69-6.717-12.317-11.818" />

    <path class="secondpath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
   M285.249,285.252c0,0,0.654-8.212-8.864-10.544c-9.519-2.334-16.796,8.211-10.825,17.449c2.613-1.12,5.226,0.652,5.599,2.52
   c0.373,1.866-1.213,4.199-3.826,4.199" />

    <path class="thirdpath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
   M257.815,307.553c0,0-3.732,5.879,2.333,8.118c6.065,2.241,5.318-8.118,8.865-9.237c3.545-1.119,11.943-2.519,11.943-10.265
   c0-7.744-6.398-16.451-17.522-11.958" />
  </g>

  <line class="row1col1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="319.41" y1="287.987" x2="324.156" y2="286.627" />

  <line class="row1col2" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="328.667" y1="285.335" x2="332.744" y2="284.167" />

  <line class="row2col3" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="338.25" y1="301.171" x2="343.41" y2="301.171" />

  <line class="row2col2" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="328.667" y1="301.171" x2="333.75" y2="301.171" />

  <line class="row2col1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="319.41" y1="301.171" x2="324.156" y2="301.171" />

  <line class="row3col1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="313.741" y1="314.625" x2="319.41" y2="315.987" />

  <line class="row3col2" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="323.741" y1="316.746" x2="329.667" y2="318.142" />

</svg>
```

Comment: Wow, cool! This is what I want. Thank you so much! How to remove the fade in fade out effect?

Comment: @Eelyn: Sorry, didn't get what you are referring to by the fade-in fade-out effect. You want the lines to appear instantaneously instead of fading in?

Comment: yes, this is what I mean. Sorry because I didn't explain it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the animation times. The delay only works for the first animation.
You should also move the non prefixed properties to the front.

I made an animation that blinks in 2 seconds every 5 seconds(total 5s).

```css
.firstpath {
  stroke-dasharray: 1500;
  animation: firstanimate 5s linear forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes firstanimate {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 1500; }
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}

.secondpath {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  animation: secondanimate 5s linear forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes secondanimate {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 500; }
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}

.thirdpath {
  stroke-dasharray: 500;
  animation: thirdanimate 5s linear forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes thirdanimate {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 500; }
  to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}


.row1col1 {
  animation: blink1 5s step-start 0s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink1 5s step-start 0s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink1 {
    0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  
  80% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}

@keyframes blink1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}

.row1col2 {
  animation: blinkl2 5s step-start 0s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink2 5s step-start 0s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  
  90% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@keyframes blink2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  
  90% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
.row1col3 {
  animation: blinkl3 5s step-start 0s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink3 5s step-start 0s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  
  95% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@keyframes blink3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  
  95% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="841.89px" height="595.28px" viewBox="0 0 841.89 595.28" enable-background="new 0 0 841.89 595.28" xml:space="preserve">
  
 <g>
  <path class="firstpath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
   M253.441,284.167c0,0-0.883-14.535,15.429-18.551c5.364-1.32,15.943-0.665,21.667,6.79c13.859,18.051-3.235,32.286-8.087,37.262
   c-4.853,4.979-7.713,21.027-17.543,20.528c-9.829-0.497-12.69-6.717-12.317-11.818"/>
   
  <path class="secondpath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
   M285.249,285.252c0,0,0.654-8.212-8.864-10.544c-9.519-2.334-16.796,8.211-10.825,17.449c2.613-1.12,5.226,0.652,5.599,2.52
   c0.373,1.866-1.213,4.199-3.826,4.199"/>
   
  <path class="thirdpath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
   M257.815,307.553c0,0-3.732,5.879,2.333,8.118c6.065,2.241,5.318-8.118,8.865-9.237c3.545-1.119,11.943-2.519,11.943-10.265
   c0-7.744-6.398-16.451-17.522-11.958"/>
 </g>

 <line class="row1col1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="319.41" y1="287.987" x2="324.156" y2="286.627"/>

 <line class="row1col2" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="328.667" y1="285.335" x2="332.744" y2="284.167"/>

 <line class="row1col3" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="338.25" y1="301.171" x2="343.41" y2="301.171"/>

 <line class="row1col2" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="328.667" y1="301.171" x2="333.75" y2="301.171"/>

 <line class="row1col1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="319.41" y1="301.171" x2="324.156" y2="301.171"/>

 <line class="row1col1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="313.741" y1="314.625" x2="319.41" y2="315.987"/>

 <line class="row1col2" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="323.741" y1="316.746" x2="329.667" y2="318.142"/>
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much. I will adjust the animation myself.